# CRM Dynamics 2015 Include JQuery in Web Resource

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a standalone web resource inside CRM Dynamics that is being loaded in an iframe.

JQquery is now included as a default library in CRM dynamics so I'm including the following in my web resource to load jquery (this was copied from the main home page of CRM Dynamics).

```
<script id="/_static/_common/scripts/jquery1.7.2.min.js?ver=-1896091690" src="/_static/_common/scripts/jquery1.7.2.min.js?ver=-1896091690" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I'm wondering is, is there a better way to do this in case the version changes so the cache won't break as soon as the version number changes?

Full html web resource page...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link id="/_common/styles/fonts.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_common/styles/fonts.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="/_common/styles/global.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_common/styles/global.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="/_common/styles/theme.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;theme=outlook15white&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_common/styles/theme.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;theme=Outlook15White&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="/_forms/controls/controls.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_forms/controls/controls.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="/_controls/notifications/notifications.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_controls/notifications/notifications.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="/_forms/controls/form.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_forms/controls/form.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link id="/_common/styles/dialogs.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" href="/_common/styles/dialogs.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-1896091690" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script id="/_static/_common/scripts/jquery1.7.2.min.js?ver=-1896091690" src="/_static/_common/scripts/jquery1.7.2.min.js?ver=-1896091690" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="/_common/global.ashx?ver=-1896091690" src="/_common/global.ashx?ver=-1896091690" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        body content here
    </body>
</html>
```

I did a little more digging and found a reference to this javascript function that looks like it is used to download jquery and other libraries...

```
loadScriptAdv('\x2f_static\x2f_common\x2fscripts\x2fjquery1.7.2.min.js\x3fver\x3d-1896091690', '\x2f_static\x2f_common\x2fscripts\x2fjquery1.7.2.min.js\x3fver\x3d-1896091690', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a custom namespace for your jQuery library

Tutorial:

[jQuery and jQuery UI with Dynamics CRM 2011 & 2013](http://develop1.net/public/post/jQueryNamespacing.aspx)

Comment: I'd like to use the same jquery library that is already loaded on the previous page and cached instead of downloading another version of the same library.

Comment: what if after you install a rollup or a crm online update is installed Microsoft changes its jQuery library name? In my opinion you shouldn't use also their css directly